How to declare h.JSX for intrinsic HTML elements?
I would like to use custom h.JSX declaration instead of global.JSX, how to do it?
Example below playground would fail, how to make it work?
The TypeScript docs say the h.JSX will be picked up instead of the global.JSX, but it doesn't work, quote from TS docs:

If the factory is defined as React.createElement (the default), the compiler will check for React.JSX before checking for a global JSX. If the factory is defined as h, it will check for h.JSX before a global JSX.

/** @jsx h */

interface ElBuilder {
  (tag: any, attrs: Record<string, any> | null, ...content: any[]): any
  JSX(tag: any, attrs: Record<string, any> | null, ...content: any[]): any
}

const h: ElBuilder = function(tag, attrs, ...content) {
  console.log('h', tag, attrs, content)
}
h.JSX = h

console.log(<div></div>)
// ^Error: JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.ts(7026)


Solution
/** @jsx h */

export namespace h {
  export namespace JSX {
    export interface IntrinsicElements {
      [tag: string]: any
    }
  }
}

interface ElBuilder {
  (tag: any, attrs: Record<string, any> | null, ...content: any[]): any
}

const h: ElBuilder = function(tag, attrs, ...content) {
  console.log('h', tag, attrs, content)
}

console.log(<div></div>)

